# How to get repo GitHub url havig ssh to clone with?

Tags: git, github

I have `ssh://ninsun/var/git/krymsky` Is it possible to find out GitHub url of the repo?

Might it be not a GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a GitHub URL. If you can cd into the git repo, use `git remote show origin` (assuming `origin` is the name of the remote pointing to GitHub) to see the full GitHub clone URL.

It should be something like

```
git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

It may also be possible the repo is not hosted on GitHub (for sure that's not a GitHub URL).